# How can I get userdefined fields on Microsoft Outlook Tasks to be shared exactly as they are on my screen?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007

I am trying to create a to do list for my team of what all is needing to be done and so that they can assign themselves to each particular task. I am doing all this as a task in microsoft outlook. In order to do this I had to create two additional columns for that were user defined to have them type stuff in. However, when I go to share the to do list with my team the only thing that is showing are the original column fields not the user defined column fields that I created that are editable. How can I get the user definied columns to show up on the peoples tasks list I am sharing this with? Thanks

Comment: we run exchange 2010 and our clients are running Outlook 2007. In the public folder, we have created a couple of shared Task folders. Logged in as the administrator, we have given the appropriate permissions, created a new list called HF and defined the views for it. I then give the permissions to the rest of the users which are Editor permission. When I log in as a test user, I can access the HF Task but I don't see the custom defined view for it. I'm not sure how to get that to show up for everyone.

Comment: Views are not stored in the Public Folder. They are stored in Outlook or a user's Exchange mailbox. You would need to export the view and import it on the viewers' computers for them to have it. There should be a group policy option for importing views without having to do it manually, though. 
How do I do the last 2 sentences step by step

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the folder view to show these columns.